# Virtuemart Queries

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I'm having troubles in a website that uses Virtuemart(2). If I enter a main category with a lot of products, it takes ages for the page to load. There are more than 1k products in this category, and Virtuemart tries to Query all off them. Even if the category view is set on 16 products.

If I look in the debug mode I see things like this:

> 1078 × SELECT `ordering`,`id`    FROM
>   `nsnpz_virtuemart_product_categories`
>
> 1078 × SELECT * 
>       FROM `nsnpz_virtuemart_product_prices`
>
> 1078 × SELECT `virtuemart_media_id`    FROM
>   `nsnpz_virtuemart_product_medias`

If I look deeper in all the queries, I see he is loading products on page number 17, even if I'm at page one.

This doesn't make any sense.. In total the page creates 10465 queries for 16 products on a  page.

Does anyone else have this problem too? Or is there a way I can lower the amount of queries?

Comment: Report this to the developers of VirtueMart so they can possibly release an update to deal with it. It's things like this why so many people are moving away from VirtueMart

Comment: I will :)
This is already a reason I'm building on different platforms already. But I don't want to rebuild this website, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem.
The default category ordering was set on Product Sales. Because of that he was Querying all the product sales, for each product.
If I set the default product ordering from price, Low -> High, I only have around 1500 queries.